# To-Many Relationship with iOS Core Data

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data

I know there are many questions related to this topic on SO, but I can't seem to find one that answers my question!

I have a relationship between a FactSheet and Image, like this:
[image: FactSheet and Image relationship]

I am parsing an internal JSON file (just one time) to import the data into Core Data.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        // Create the managed object context
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = managedObjectContext();

        // Save the managed object context
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Error while saving %@", ([error localizedDescription] != nil) ? [error localizedDescription] : @"Unknown Error");
            exit(1);
        }

        NSError* err = nil;
        NSString* dataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FactSheets" ofType:@"json"];
        NSArray* FactSheets = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath]
                                                     options:kNilOptions
                                                       error:&err];

        [FactSheets enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            FactSheet *factSheet = [NSEntityDescription
                                          insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"FactSheet"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
            factSheet.name = [obj objectForKey:@"name"];
            factSheet.details = [obj objectForKey:@"details"];

            NSArray* images=[obj objectForKey:@"images"];


            [images enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id img, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

                Image *image = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Image"
                                                         inManagedObjectContext:factSheet.managedObjectContext];


                image.path = [img objectForKey:@"path"];

                if([img objectForKey:@"caption"]!=[NSNull null]) {
                    image.caption = [img objectForKey:@"caption"];
                }

                if([img objectForKey:@"label"]!=[NSNull null]) {
                    image.label = [img objectForKey:@"label"];
                }

                if([img objectForKey:@"galleryThumb"]!=[NSNull null]) {
                    image.galleryThumb = [img objectForKey:@"galleryThumb"];
                }

                [factSheet addImageObject:image];

            }];



            NSError *error;
            if (![context save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
        }];

        //Test listing
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"FactSheet"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
        NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
        for (FactSheet *fs in fetchedObjects) {
            NSLog(@"Name: %@", fs.name);
            for (Image *i in fs.images) {
                NSLog(@"Image Path: %@",i.path);
            }
        }

    }



    return 0;
}
```

Running this works until I try to print it out with NSLog.  It breaks on the following line:

```
for (Image *i in fs.images) {
```

With an "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error.  When I open the .sqlite file in SQLite Database Browser, it seems like the data has been inserted how I would think it should be (although I'm by no means a SQLite expert!).

I guess my question is:  Am I inserting the objects into core data correctly and just incorrect in my attempts to print it back out --or--, should I be storing the objects into core data a different way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the call to this:
`for (Image *i in fs.image) {`

Based on your model, the relationship name is `image` so you can either update your model or your loop code.

Comment: Thank you, that did it.  When Core Data auto-generated the NSSet in my header file, I thought it was confusing that it was a set of images and called `NSSet *image` so I made it plural.  I guess that was enough to confuse Xcode!  Changing it back to singular in the h file fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try with - 
for (Image *i in fs.image) {
Notice, it should be fs.image instead of fs.images.